# iOS 7 set UITabbarItem as unselected

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

When a tab bar item is selected, I want to set it such as that it looks like its unselected (i.e, I don't want to the selected tab bar item to have the selected tint color applied to it). Is this possible?